# ¿Se dice "el alma mía" o "el alma mío"?

Tags: género, artículos, concordancia-gramatical

¿Por qué en este versiculo de la Biblia que sigue se dice "alma mía" y no "alma mío"?

> Salmos 42:1-2 Reina-Valera 1960 (RVR1960)
>
> 42. Como el ciervo brama por las corrientes de las aguas,
> Así clama por ti, oh Dios, **el alma mía**.

Comment: Related: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/8436/why-is-a-feminine-adjective-used-in-el-agua-poco-profunda

Answer (score 5):

It has been translated as *alma mía* because *alma* is a feminine noun. The fact that it is preceded by *el* is because it is stressed on the first *a* and it would not be euphonious to say *la alma mía*

Comment: This should reference some kind of FAQ for newcomers to the Spanish language.  A lot of people who speak Spanish as a second language are totally unfamiliar with feminine nouns that take el rather than la

Comment: @WalterMitty and indeed on this site https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/44/why-is-agua-masculine-in-singular-form-and-feminine-in-plural-el-agua-la but I suspect unless you have an idea about the rule it is hard to find it searching the internet.

Comment: That's why it needs to be in a FAQ.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by 'Walter Mitty's' comment it's important to explain why `el alma`, rather than `la alma` (maybe it's the origin of OP's confusion on the use of the feminine or masculine possesive).

**Alma is a feminine noun**. However, there's an interesting rule in Spanish regarding the use of `la` (the feminine definite article) and `el` (masculine definite article). The [Diccionario Panhispánico de Dudas (DPD)](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=el) states the following:

> **2.1.** El artículo femenino la toma obligatoriamente la forma el cuando se antepone a sustantivos femeninos que comienzan por /a/ tónica.

In plain english, this means that we have to use `el` in all feminine nouns that begin with a stressed letter a. **This doesn't mean that the gender of the noun is changing!** We only change the article. Exemples (these are all feminine nouns):

- Agua: **El** Agua (Á-GU-A. Stress in the first a, therefore we use `el`).
- Águila: **El** Águila (Á-GUI-LA. Stress in the first a, therefore we use `el`).
- Aviación: **LA** Aviación (A-VIA-CIÓN. Stress on the last syllable, therefore we use `la`).

In your example (`el alma mía`) **we use the feminine possessive** (`mía`) because `alma` **is a feminine noun**. However, we use `el` (the masculine article), because the first "a" in `alma` is stressed.

Comment: It might also be useful to cite the etymology of "la".   Centuries ago, it was something like "ela"   (spelling?).  In cases like agua, it was shortened to el,  while in most cases it was shortened to la.  Is there a good authority to cite on this?

Comment: I found this reference, under Etimología 2,  but it's perhaps not authoritative.  https://es.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/el

Comment: Son buenos ejemplos.

Comment: By your comment, "This doesn't mean that the genre of the noun is changing! " do you mean "This doesn't mean that the GENDER of the noun is changing!" ???

Comment: @JckGutknecht. Yep, sorry. I will change it.

Comment: Technically in this case, when we say *el agua* we're still using a feminine article, it just happens to share the form with the masculine one.  So we can say it's an alloform of the feminine article.  This is similar to when we say *se lo regalé*.  The *se* isn't a reflexive pronoun, it's just a special form of *le(s)* that happens to match the reflexive, but it's still an indirect object pronoun.

Comment: @WalterMitty Hey, I think you're right! Again, in the DPD, there's an explanation on how the Latin demonstrative 'illa' evolved to 'ela', which lost it's 'a' before words with a vowel.

Comment: @guifa yep! it's still a feminine article that takes the form of 'el'. And indeed it's a similar phenomenon as in Le(s) -> se. I think the correct term for this words it's homónimos, although I'm not sure if they are homónimos gramaticales or homónimos morfológicos.